# How do I get Cassandra to start when there is an error about "Connection refused"?

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, cassandra

I installed Cassandra on Ubuntu 16.04.  (I have gotten Cassandra to work on RedHat.  But now I want it to work on Ubuntu.)  The installation seemed to go smoothly.  I run this command to prove that Cassandra is active:

```
sudo service cassandra status
```

This command returns this output:

```
cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data 
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: enabled)   
Active: active (exited) since Tue 2017-12-26 19:22:43 UTC; 8min ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)   Process: 1252 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)     
Tasks: 0    Memory: 0B         CPU: 0
```

The above "bad" concerns me.  But it does return "Active."  It seems like there is no major problem.

When I run "cqlsh" or "cqlsh 127.0.0.1" I get

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1':
>   error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error:
>   Connection refused")})

I used nmap to test port 9042.  The port is not blocked.  There is not firewall installed either.

I rebooted the server.  I tried modifying cassandra-env.sh.  I uncommented a stanza and set it to be 127.0.0.1:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1"
```

Nothing I do works.  I expect to enter a different command prompt when I type in "cqlsh" or "cqlsh 127.0.0.1".  But this does not happen. What do I do to have "cqlsh" work on an Ubuntu server?

Comment: Use code formatting for command output, please.

Comment: Try `sudo fuser -n tcp 9042`, if it returns a pid, there is at least a process running and listening on this port. Then try also to connect to 127.0.1.1 (https://askubuntu.com/a/754219/367444).

Comment: That `sudo fuser -n tcp 9042` returns nothing.  `sudo service cassandra status` shows the Cassandra service is active.  `cqlsh 127.0.1.1` returns
`Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.1.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.1.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`

Comment: I am facing this issue. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. cassandra service is active and installation completed successfuly. I have no other process running on port 9042. Still I can't connect to cassandra server.

Comment: if issue is resolved try to post answer . i was facing same issue. i checked all the stackoverflow  questions and my issue is not resolved.

Comment: I have the same error what is the solution please

Answer (score 0):

If you look at /var/log/cassandra/system.log you'll see:

Port already in use: ***7199***; nested exception is:java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)

This is the default port in /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh :

JMX_PORT="7199"

Changed it to another port: 7198.

This solution work for me.