# DNS not resolving eventhough I can ping DNS server on shared system

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

I am running ubuntu 16

System A: eth0 is connected to internet via proxy, eth1 is connected directly to a second computer
System B: has one NIC and it is connected to eth1 on system A

System A eth1 is set for Shared via the network manager GUI.
System B has Gateway and DNS set to System A eth1's address.  I have also tried just setting the address to match System A eth0's gateway and DNS

On System B, I can ping the DNS server so the shared connection is at least partially working.  However, when I try to connect anywhere, the DNS does not resolve not even the proxy URL.  However I can ping the IP addresses.

By default, /etc/resolv.conf is set to 127.0.1.1
I've tried setting it to 127.0.0.1, System A eth1 address, and System A eth0's DNS address

Comment: Hi, Welcome to ask ubuntu.  Please read these q/a: https://askubuntu.com/questions/754213/what-is-difference-between-localhost-address-127-0-0-1-and-127-0-1-1, https://askubuntu.com/questions/2321/what-is-the-proper-way-to-change-the-dns-ip.   They should at least help you get over a couple misunderstandings you have on networking.  (127.0.0.1 always refers to the loopback interface -- myself, not another system).  Re-asking your question after looking at those will draw better answers I suspect.

Comment: Yes, I am aware 127.0.0.1 refers to the loop back device.  I was not familiar with 127.0.1.1 until I saw the link you sent me.  This is what it was originally set to but it still did not work.  Setting /etc/resolv.conf to the actual dns server should work and I know I can connect to it because I can ping it.  My issue is more with getting DNS to work on a shared connection.  I used the GUI to set it up but it still does not work.  I've never encountered an instance where I could ping the DNS, yet it didnt work even after setting it.